# Shopify Liquid - Section Blocks is not paginateable

Tags: arrays, shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-api

I need to implement the infinite-scroll js to my section blocks.
but infinite-scroll js requires pagination, so I am trying to paginate the section blocks but it says 'section.blocks' is not paginateable.

```html
    {%- paginate section.blocks by 5 -%}
      {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
    
    
        <!-- render here -->
    
    
      {%- endfor -%}
    
      {{ paginate | default_pagination: next: 'Older', previous: 'Newer' }}
    {%- endpaginate -%}
```

Is there a way to make it paginateable? Thanks!

Comment: Nopes, but you can use the use AJAX to list the pending blocks from another page.

Comment: if you want to load them on demand then you need to modify the HTML using JS in AJAX response, but into liquid code, you can paginate them like collection or products.

Comment: I had a workaround with my problem with pagination and infinitescroll at the same time still using the sections blocks. Thanks! @Onkar

Comment: I don't know what workaround is on your side, but currently, you can't paginate the block inside a block in the normal way you need to adapt a custom solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion here? You paginate a resource like products, or products in a collection. By saying you want to paginate blocks in a section, you are saying you have 50 or more blocks? What? Is that the intended use of a block? They are just a convenience in a theme for rendering some useful aspect of a store, not as an actual resource like products. Are you sure you are approaching this correctly?

Comment: Yep,  I have more than 50 blocks actually and yes I understand what you mean. 
But the site has complex settings and layout that I need to use blocks for that.